# How to do this without a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, dataframe, row

The following code makes a data frame full of 0's with the column and row labels being numbers:

```
#make blank data frame, label the columns and rows
data <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)) 
colnames <- seq(from = 1, to = 4, by = 1)
names(data)<- sprintf("%.0f", colnames)
rownames <- seq(from=3, to=12, by=3)
rownames(data) <- sprintf("%.0f", rownames)
```

My question is, given the above data frame, how can I fill in the data frame with each cell taking on the value of the row label multiplied by the column label NOT using a for-loop as I have in the code that follows.  I would like to know how to do this using a vectorized method and not have to loop through each individual cell.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(data)){
        data[i,j] <- as.numeric(rownames(data)[i])*as.numeric(colnames(data)[j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `rownames` and `colnames` vectors to `numeric`s and take their outer product like this:

```
> as.numeric(rownames(data)) %o% as.numeric(colnames(data))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6    9   12
[2,]    6   12   18   24
[3,]    9   18   27   36
[4,]   12   24   36   48
```

and make the appropriate modifications, if desired:

```
data2 <- data.frame(
  as.numeric(rownames(data)) %o% 
  as.numeric(colnames(data)))
names(data2) <- names(data)
##
> data2
   1  2  3  4
1  3  6  9 12
2  6 12 18 24
3  9 18 27 36
4 12 24 36 48
```

There's a (less compact) version of `%o%` which does not restrict you to the outer *product*:

```
outer(as.numeric(rownames(data)),
      as.numeric(colnames(data)),
      FUN=function(x,y){ x*(2/3) + y/3 })
         [,1]     [,2] [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 2.333333 2.666667    3 3.333333
[2,] 4.333333 4.666667    5 5.333333
[3,] 6.333333 6.666667    7 7.333333
[4,] 8.333333 8.666667    9 9.333333
```

In the default case of `outer`, `FUN="*"`, which is equivalent to using `%o%`.

Comment: Clever solution.  What if I need to perform another function of the column names and row names?  For example, if I have defined a function a(x,y), how would I input the proper row name and col name to this function?

Comment: It's hard to say as the solution will vary depending on what `a(x,y)` is; a vectorized approach will almost surely be possible though. Generally speaking, `mapply` would probably be a good starting point - whether or not it is the *best* approach will depend on the particular operation though.

Comment: OK.  I think I figured it out after thinking about it a little.  It's just a variation on your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - maybe not.  Let's say the function is defined as : `a(x,y) <- ((2*x)/3) + ((3*y)/9)`.  This is pseudo-code, BTW.